# Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to read files from a directory with camel file consumer but I need my route to be transacted. So I can not use threads inside the rout.
Is it ok to write multiply routes to read from the same endpoint (same directory) with a little change between the uris (for example the sort type) , and like this to avoid the Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed exception ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah sure you can do that, mind that you will have competing consumes for the same files now, so mind about read-locks. By default Camel use the marker file.

You can also use different delay so they dont poll at the same interval/time. And you can sort by random to make less chance of processing the same files.

Comment: suppose a file is now being consume by route1 , and has a marker file on it (suppose we are using readLock=changed) . Will route2 be able to read this file also ? if not - what problem of competing consumes I have here ?

Comment: Read more in the Camel docs about read-locks. changed will not work for exclusive as both consumers can detect when the file is no longer changed and start reading it, however a marker file is exclusive. Or potential fileLock but that depends on the JDK and file system you are using, read the JDK doc/javadoc about that etc.

Comment: thank you Claus. markerFile option cause problem with large files as camel start read the file before the file is fully written.But I know that changed is also using a marker file , no ? so what is the problem ? and what about rename option ? will it not solve both problems ?

Comment: Ask the computer

Comment: why do you say : By default Camel use the marker file ? in http://camel.apache.org/file2.html I see that the default is : readLock
none